# Why is it possible to declare more then 1 configuration section in the onet.xml?

Tags: custom, web-template, onet

I am using sharepoint 2010 and vs2010.

I created a custom web template and start with the onet.xml from the teamsite. I see 4 configuration sections. Why there are more then 1 configuration sections? Is it possible to select one of them in sharepoint?

```
    <Configurations>
    <Configuration ID="-1" Name="NewWeb" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master" />
    <Configuration ID="0" Name="Default" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master">
some stuff
</Configuration>

 <Configuration ID="1" Name="Blank" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master">
some stuff
</Configuration>

<Configuration ID="2" Name="DWS" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master">
some stuff
</Configuration>

</Configurations>
```

I see also differance module element related to the configuration:

```
<Modules>
    <Module Name="Default" Url="" Path="">
      <File Url="default.aspx" NavBarHome="True">
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,announce_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" MobileView="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Left" />
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,calendar_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" MobileView="TRUE" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="2" />
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,links_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" MobileView="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Right" WebPartOrder="1" />
        <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" Url="~site" ID="1002" Position="Start" />
        <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" Url="" ID="0" Position="Start" />
      </File>
    </Module>
    <Module Name="DefaultBlank" Url="" Path="">
      <File Url="default.aspx" NavBarHome="True" Type="Ghostable">
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,announce_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" MobileView="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Left" />
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,calendar_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" MobileView="TRUE" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="2" />
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,links_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" MobileView="TRUE" WebPartZoneID="Right" WebPartOrder="1" />
        <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" Url="~site" ID="1002" Position="Start" />
        <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" Url="" ID="0" Position="Start" />
      </File>
    </Module>
    <Module Name="DWS" Url="">
      <File Url="defaultdws.aspx" Name="default.aspx">
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,announce_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Top" />
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,links_Folder;" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="Right" WebPartOrder="2" />
        <View List="$Resources:core,shareddocuments_Folder;" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="Left" />
        <View List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,tasks_Folder;" BaseViewID="7" WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="2" />
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Right" WebPartOrder="1">
          <![CDATA[
                   <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
                      <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                      <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.MembersWebPart</TypeName>
                      <Title>$Resources:wp_Members;</Title>
                      <Description>$Resources:wp_Members_Desc;</Description>
                      <FrameType>Standard</FrameType>
                      <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
                      </WebPart>
                   ]]>
        </AllUsersWebPart>
        <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" Url="~site" ID="1002" Position="Start" />
        <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" ID="0" Position="Start" />
      </File>
    </Module>
  </Modules>
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, You can have a site definition with more then 1 configuration, and you can use one of them to create a site,

for example, when we try to create a site we give web template name its configuration ID,

Let say you got a site definition with two configuration, 1 and 0,

```
STS#0        Team Site
STS#1        Blank Site
```

You can create a Team site by using this code,

```
admService.CreateSite("http://Server_Name/sites/SiteCollection_Name",
        "Title", "Description", 1033, "STS#0", 
        "Domain_Name\\User_Alias","User_Display_Name",
        "User_E-mail","","");
```

Options like Module and Configuration are there so that you can create a different sites with different components and layouts and even properties of components without creating different site definitions.

**Still Confused ?**

[image]

This diagram should clear all of your confusions with site definitions if not then,

[How to: Use Site Definition Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441616%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

**Edit**

Each configuration has a attribute "Title" which can be used to create sites based on configurations.

Comment: Jeez where'd you find that screenshot of SPS2003? Haven't seen that one for about 6 years now!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583160(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Maaannn.. it's like seeing photos of yourself from preschool!

Comment: Haha, I know what you mean, I was always confused with site definitions and web templates and then I came across this picture, it actually cleared my concepts like crystal, very useful :D

Comment: ok, but when I dont create a new site programmatically. Just the normal way, site actions -> create new site. Which configuration will be used?

Comment: @KHA why you don't read the links I given? you use configuration title to create a new site.

Comment: I dont have a webTemp.xml file where I declare all my configurations. And it is still working. The only thing I would like to know is, which configuration will be used default? In my example above I have 4 (id -1 till 2).